# circular array trouble

Tags: modifiers

Trouble with circular array. I get a line array, even realative offset are set to 0, se pictures.
I have tried to look at several demo of how to do, but I do not get the right result. A week agoe this work fine, so what combination I have press on keyboard....
I have 3 screenshot of this.   First are a box and a empty. Second array modifier realtive offset, and third cirucular array where empte turned 60degrees. [image]Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

just in edit mode rotate the cube 60 degrees
[image]

Comment: Thank you. but I tried to do something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLi-gnq9DLs, where you place a empty and make a cirucular array around this

Comment: I see what you are missing, the empty is going to be the center of the circle don't share the same position of the box but the box is going to have the pivot in the same position of the empy,  them try constant offset no relative offset in the modifier

Comment: Yes you are right. I try to use a empty as a center. Constant offset do not work. In several videos, thay use realtiv offset. I have tried allso to move piviot but no. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: I have solved it. Set origin to cursor, and then snap to empty. Then array with empty as origen work